# Typescript: How can I return the first object in an array which has a unique key value pair from any objects in a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, key-value

I want to return the first item in an array of objects that does not have a matching id to any object in a separate array. For example,

```
arrary1 = [
 { name: "object1", id: 1, coordinates: undefined}
 { name: "object2", id: 2, coordinates: undefined}
 { name: "object3", id: 3, coordinates: undefined}
 { name: "object4", id: 4, coordinates: undefined}
 { name: "object5", id: 5, coordinates: undefined}
]

and 

array2 = [
 { name: "object1", id: 1, coordinates: [3,2]}
 { name: "object2", id: 2, coordinates: [1,1]}
 { name: "object3", id: 3, coordinates: [3,6]}
]

Should return:

{ name: "object4", id: 4, coordinates: undefined}
```

I want to return the first item in array1 that does not have the same `id` as any of the objects in array2. (I cannot just compare the objects as a whole because there might be other differing key value pairs. I only care about the `id`.)

I am trying:

```
    const firstUniqueItem = find(array1, function (object1) {
      return !array2.some((object2) => {object2.id === object1.id})
    });
```

This will work when array2 is empty, but still just returns the first item of array1 when array2 has has an object with a matching id.

What do I need to fix? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: At least one problem is `... => { ... }` is a statement block that doesn't automatically return the result. Either remove the curly braces so the body is an expression that's automatically returned, or add `return` before your equality check.

Comment: Also, `arrary1` vs. `array1`, and attempting to use a global `find` function that doesn't exist. (should probably be `array1.find()`).    Creating a snippet to show the actual problem would be really helpful.  As the question is written since the code doesn't run and seems to be typed in, it's impossible to tell if your actual code uses a 'return' or not, or what else might be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to filter `array1` and remove any occurrence of `array2`, then take the first item.

```
array1.filter(a => !array2.find(b => b.id==a.id))[0] || false
```

The `|| false` at the end gives  you a boolean just in case there isn't a match. Otherwise you'd get `undefined`

```js
let array1 = [
 { name: "object1", id: 1, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object2", id: 2, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object3", id: 3, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object4", id: 4, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object5", id: 5, coordinates: undefined}
]

let array2 = [
 { name: "object1", id: 1, coordinates: [3,2]},
 { name: "object2", id: 2, coordinates: [1,1]},
 { name: "object3", id: 3, coordinates: [3,6]}
]

let answer = array1.filter(a => !array2.find(b => b.id==a.id))[0] || false;
console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @carcigenicate mentions in his comment, the function you pass to `some()` does not return the value.

There are a few other weird things about your code, creating an actual snippet that ran would help.   For instance your first array is declared as `arrary1` but used as `array`.  Also you use a `find(array1)` function that doesn't exist in javascript, I assume you mean `array1.find()`.

```js
array1 = [
 { name: "object1", id: 1, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object2", id: 2, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object3", id: 3, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object4", id: 4, coordinates: undefined},
 { name: "object5", id: 5, coordinates: undefined}
]

array2 = [
 { name: "object1", id: 1, coordinates: [3,2]},
 { name: "object2", id: 2, coordinates: [1,1]},
 { name: "object3", id: 3, coordinates: [3,6]}
]

//Should return:
//{ name: "object4", id: 4, coordinates: undefined}

const firstUniqueItem = array1.find(function (object1) {
  return !array2.some((object2) => {
    return object2.id === object1.id
  })
});
    
console.log(`firstUniqueItem: ${JSON.stringify(firstUniqueItem)}`)
```

Of course this is horribly inefficient.   If you have 1000 elements in array2 and 1001 elements in array1, you could be doing a million comparisons to find the one element that isn't in array2.  You can make this faster by first creating an object with property names that are the ids in array2 with values 'true' (or anything truthy).

```js
const mappedIds = array2.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr.id] = true;
  return prev;
}, {});

const firstUniqueItem = array1.find(x => !mappedIds[x.id]);
```